# Spring boot 3 - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: spring-boot

My POM dependencies

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```html
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    Employee employee;
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {

        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

    //test method
    //@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    //@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getResponseTest() {
        System.out.println("This point it is working");
        return "Hello!";
    }
```

When I created the app my endpoints were worked as expected. Then I did connect my app with mysql and now DB part is working but endpoints are not working. I added a simple test route to identify the issue . It seems like endpoints are correct and except for the DB part I haven't done any other changes in controller too.
I double checked everything but I am keep getting 404 at http://localhost:8081/test.

Comment: have u tried to add @RequestMapping("/") after @RestController

Comment: yes but it is not working

Comment: In your question you are talking about endpoint on port 8081 - http://localhost:8081/test Default in Spring is 8080. Are you sure you are using calling port? Or you intentionally changed port to 8081?